# With Xubuntu 21.10 on 2008 MacBook, why does keyboard only function as a 10-key pad?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, macbook

Just installed Xubuntu 20.10 on my 2008 MacBook (4,1). Most keys don't function, but one group behaves like a 10-key pad. Selected standard English keyboard layout during install. Tried several other keyboard layouts. None worked. Can't type terminal commands or connect to wifi without alpha characters. Since keyboard seems stuck in a "numlock on" mode, I thought of checking Bios/EFI for a way to disable numlock, but powering up with CMD-S won't bring up EFI since the Xubuntu install.

Comment: My solution: replaced Xubuntu with Ubuntu Mate 20.04.3 LTS. It worked beautifully right from the start. Leaving the question up because I'm still curious, and maybe replies will help somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the numlock from the terminal using `numlockx off`.
This will allow to turn off the numlock.

You can do this using the virtual keyboard (onboard) and the terminal emulator. It's in Menu > Accessories > Onboard